# Adding another drop down list to a dynamic php, Mysql form with 2 other drop downs

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Hi I am working on a php drop down list that pulls its records from a database. I have got the first and the second drop downs working. I however need help implementing the 3rd drop down. Here is what i have so far. The first 2 are working fine. I just really need to make the 3rd one work. It relies on input from the first and the 2nd one.

index.php

```
   <?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");


$query ="SELECT * FROM campus";

?>
<html>
<head>
    <TITLE>Campus and Faculty Select</TITLE>
<head>
<style>
        body{width:610px;}
        .frmDronpDown {border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;background-color:#C8EEFD;margin: 2px 0px;padding:40px;}
        .demoInputBox {padding: 10px;border: #F0F0F0 1px solid;border-radius: 4px;background-color: #FFF;width: 50%;}
        .row{padding-bottom:15px;}
</style>
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function getcampus_id(val) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_faculty.php",
        data:'campus_id='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#faculty-list").html(data);
        }
        });
    }

    function getfaculty_id(val) {
        alert(val)
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_course.php",
        data:'faculty_id='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#course-list").html(data);
        }
        });
    }

    function selectcampus_id(val) {
    $("#search-box").val(val);
    $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="rightcol" action="form.php" method="post" class="container">
    <div class="frmDronpDown">
        <div class="row">
            <label>Campus:</label><br/>
                <select name="campus" id="campus-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getcampus_id(this.value);">
                    <option value="">Select Campus</option>
                    <?php
                                $query ="SELECT * FROM campus";
                                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                                //loop
                                while($campus = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) :
                                //foreach ($result as $campus){
                            ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $campus["campus_id"]; ?>"> <?php echo $campus["name"]; ?></option>
                        <?php
                        endwhile;
                        ?>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Faculty:</label><br/>
                <select name="faculty" id="faculty-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getfaculty_id(this.value);>
                    <option value="">Select Faculty</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Course:</label><br/>
                <select name="course" id="course-list" class="demoInputBox" >
                    <option value="">Select Course</option>
                </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

get_faculty.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once("dbcontroller.php");

if(!empty($_POST["campus_id"])) {
    $campus_id = $_POST["campus_id"];
    $query ="SELECT * FROM faculty WHERE campus_id = $campus_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if ( $result === false ) {
        echo mysqli_error($con);
        exit;
    }

    echo '<option value="">Select Campus</option>';

    while ( $faculty = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) :  
        echo '<option value="' . $faculty['faculty_id'] . '">';
        echo $faculty['faculty_name']; 
        echo '</option>';
    endwhile;
    }
?>
```

and finally get_course.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once("dbcontroller.php");

if(!empty($_POST["campus_id"])) {
    $course_id = $_POST["campus_id"].$POST_["faculty_id"];
    $query ="SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE `campus_id`and `faculty_id` = $course_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if ( $result === false ) {
        echo mysqli_error($con);
        exit;
    }

    echo '<option value="">Select Campus</option>';

    while ( $course = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) :   
        echo '<option value="' . $course['course_id'] . '">';
        echo $faculty['course_name']; 
        echo '</option>';
    endwhile;
    }
?>
```

Comment: why is your `onChange="getfaculty_id(this.value);"` on your 3rd select and not your 2nd select?

Comment: @Sean Still nothing.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: [How SQL injection works](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) - Don't let it happen to you!

Comment: I am confused by these 2 lines, that have multiple errors - `$course_id = $_POST["campus_id"].$POST_["faculty_id"]; $query ="SELECT * FROM \`course\` WHERE \`campus_id\`and \`faculty_id\` = $course_id";` It should probably be `$campus_id = $_POST["campus_id"]; $faculty_id = $_POST["faculty_id"];  $query ="SELECT * FROM \`course\` WHERE \`campus_id\` = $campus_id AND \`faculty_id\` = $faculty_id";`

Comment: @Sean Thank you for the heads up. I definitlet was not thinking security I just needed it to work. I figure that problem is with that bit of code. Especially the query. I need it to display the caouse based on the faculty and the campus argo it should read the foreign keys of both. I am stuck at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing quote on you `onchange` of the second `select`.

use this

`<select name="faculty" id="faculty-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getfaculty_id(this.value);">
       <option value="">Select Faculty</option>
    </select>`

**EDIT**
i tried to replicated what you where trying to do and got it work. Here are the files with the edits including `mysqldump` of the database i used in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/danleyb2/77d539c0f1a8396a61eef23acb6f02fe)

The files i edited are

1. index.php
   included `campus_id` in the post request to get the course_list so we can use it for the foreign key

   ```
   function getfaculty_id(val) {

   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_course.php",
   data:{
       'faculty_id':val,
       'campus_id':$('#campus-list').val()
   },
   success: function(data){
       $("#course-list").html(data);
   }
   });
   }
   ```
2. get_course.php
   correct how you were accessing `$_POST` data, you should not do `$POST_["faculty_id"]`
   Correct `$query` as @sean suggested
   use `$course` instead of `$faculty` in the while loop for creating the `select`

   ```
   if(!empty($_POST["campus_id"])) {
   $campus_id = $_POST["campus_id"];
   $faculty_id=$_POST["faculty_id"];    
   $query ="SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE `campus_id`=$campus_id and `faculty_id` = $faculty_id";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
   if ( $result === false ) {
       echo mysqli_error($con);
       exit;
   }
   echo '<option value="">Select Course</option>';
   while ( $course = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) :   
       echo '<option value="' . $course['course_id'] . '">';
       echo $course['course_name']; 
       echo '</option>';
   endwhile;
   }
   ```

Comment: @NjonjoKiroga check out the edits i made, hope it works now